# Problem on multiplication of scalar and vector .

Tags: vectors

There are a set of three problems in the book by: Henry Ricardo, titled: A Modern Introduction to Linear Algebra, in Chap. $1$, sec. $1.1$, part $B$. The last two problems (Q.$5$, Q.$6$) are dependent on the first problem (Q.$4$).
I expect that solution to the first problem would pave the way for the last two too.

Q.$4$.
Let $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Define $x \ge 0$ to mean $x_1 \ge 0$ and $x_2 \ge 0$.
Define $x \le 0$ analogously. If $(x_1 + x_2)x \ge 0$, what must be true of $x$?

Soln. attempt: 
$(x_1 + x_2)x \ge 0\implies(x_1 + x_2)\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2 \end{bmatrix}\ge 0\implies \begin{bmatrix}x_1(x_1+x_2)\\x_2(x_1+x_2) \end{bmatrix}\ge 0\implies x_1(x_1+x_2)\ge 0, x_2(x_1+x_2)\ge 0$.

Leads to $6$ combination of possibilities for sign of values of $x_1, x_2, x_1+x_2$
If signs of $x_1, x_2$ are the same:
(i) $x_1\ge 0, x_2\ge 0$:
(ii) $x_1\le 0, x_2\le 0$:

If signs of $x_1, x_2$ are different:
Case specific combinations:
a. $x_1(x_1+x_2)$:
(iii)$x_1\ge 0, x_2\le 0, x_1+x_2\ge 0$:
(iv) $x_1\le 0, x_2\ge 0, x_1+x_2\le 0$:

b. $x_2(x_1+x_2)$:
(v)$x_2\ge 0, x_1\le 0, x_1+x_2\ge 0$:
(vi) $x_2\le 0, x_1\ge 0, x_1+x_2\le 0$:

Am unable to draw any inference that might be useful for solving the next two question below.

---

Q.$5$. Using the definition in the previous exercise, define $u \ge v$ to
mean $u- v \ge 0$, where $u$ and $v$ are vectors having the same
number of components. Consider the following vectors:
$x= \begin{bmatrix}3\\5\\-1 \end{bmatrix}, y= \begin{bmatrix}6\\5\\6 \end{bmatrix}, u = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\-2 \end{bmatrix}, v = \begin{bmatrix}4\\2\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

a. Show that $x \ge u$.
b. Show that $v \ge u$.
c. Is there any relationship between $x$ and $v$?
d. Show that $y \ge x$, $y \ge  u$, and $y \ge  v$.

Q.$6$. Extending the definitions in Exercises B4 and B5 in the obvious way, prove the following results for vectors $x, y, z$, and $w$ in $R_n$:

a. If $x \le y$ and $y \le z$, then $x \le z$.
b. If $x \le y$ and $z \le w$, then $x + z\le y+w$.
c. If $x \le y$ and $\lambda$ is a non-negative real number, then $\lambda x \le \lambda y$.
d. If $x \le y$ and $\mu$ is a negative real number, then $\mu x \ge \mu y$.

Comment: I can't really see the point of Q4. It introduces the appropriate definition, but I can't figure out what it's angling at with $(x_1 + x_2)x \ge 0$. On the other hand, I don't think you'll need any help from Q4 to answer Q5 or Q6, just the definition in Q4.

Comment: @user780985 Seems to me there is typo, it should have been that instead of scalar, there been a row vector $[x_1 x_2]$. Then the conclusion is $x_1^2 +x_2^2 \ge 0 \implies x_1, x_2 \notin \mathbb{C}$. This is useful only for ordering relationship, but that too seems far-fetched as actual values are given in Q.$5$, and real space is stated for Q.$6$.

Comment: I don't think complex numbers come anywhere near this thing, as they are not ordered. The $\ge 0$ relation wouldn't make sense over $\Bbb{C}$. (Also, pedantry commands me to point out that $x^2_1 + x^2_2$ being real and non-negative doesn't imply $x_1, x_2 \notin \Bbb{C}$, not just because every real number is in $\Bbb{C}$, but that we could also have $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = i$, for example.)

Comment: @user780985 wrongly stated complex, rather than imaginary number. Please see my last comment in the light of the modification that $x_1, x_2 \notin \mathbb{I}$.

Comment: Well, there's still the one exceptional case where $x_1 = x_2 = 0$, but all that aside, I think that even talking about $x \ge 0$ or anything similar implicitly assumes $x$ is a vector of real numbers. The possibility of a typo, that it's supposed to be $x^\top x$ instead of $(x_1 + x_2)x$, seems far-fetched, as it has nothing to do with vectors being positive or negative. I also still think that this is a very "real" question (even if it doesn't say so explicitly) and non-real complex (or quaternion, etc) numbers should not be even considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their relation is that Question $4$ first define the definition of $\ge$ for a vector so that we can write down $x \ge 0$ and we know it means entrywise nonnegative. Its use in other part of the question seems to only be using its definition of greater than equal to $0$.

In Question $5$, we then enable comparison for some of the vectors, so that $u \ge v$ means elementwise comparison and verifies that it is not a total order.

Question $6$ studies some of the property of  $\ge$.

---

More on question $4$:

More generally,  if we have 
$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)x \ge 0$$

$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$ satisfies the condition.

If $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ne 0$, we can divide it on both sides and use $6c$ and $6d$ and some verification to conclude the following result.

$$\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i =0 \right] \lor [x \ge 0] \lor [x \le 0]$$

[image]

Comment: Q.$6$ uses the definition of $\ge$ to define $\le$.In Q.$5$, the partial ordering part is the key, that would also apply to Q. $6$.

Comment: Note that if $(x_1, x_2)$ satisifes the condtion then $(x_2, x_1)$ would satisfies the condition.

Comment: So, Q.$4$ is valid for origin & both the first & third quadrants. But, if $x_1 =-x_2$, then also $x_1(x_1+x_2), x_2(x_1+x_2) =0$ . Then, such a set of points does not lie in 1st or 4th quadrants, or at origin.

Comment: yes, it include $x_1+x_2=0$ as well.

Comment: But, if the condition is stated explicitly is not clear, except in the graph.

Comment: Sorry, your earlier part (now, removed in edit)  was explicit: If $(x_1+x_2)x_1 \ge 0 $ and $(x_1+x_2) x_2 \ge 0$. If we have $x_1+x_2 = 0$, then it is satisfies.  Now, if $x_1+x_2 \ne 0$.  If $x_1+x_2 >0$, then we must have $x_1 \ge 0$ and $x_2 \ge 0$. Similarly, if $x_1+x_2 < 0$, then $x_1 \le 0$ and $x_2 \le 0$.

Hence $(x_1+x_2)x \ge 0$ describes the union of the line $x_1+x_2=0$ and the first quadrant $x \ge 0$ and the third quadrant $x \le 0$.